# Open a small floating window at cursor position

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, window, mouse-cursor

I'm writing a small proof of concept that requires me to listen to some key combination that when pressed opens a small `WPF/WinForms` window underneath the current cursor position. I'm more of a web guy so I'm having trouble starting with this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or provide some resources/examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this example for WPF. By pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key displays a `Popup` window  in advance receiving the coordinates of the mouse cursor.

**`XAML`**

```
<Window x:Class="OpenWindowForCursor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">

    <Grid>
        <Popup Name="PopupWindow"
               Placement="Relative"
               IsOpen="False"
               StaysOpen="False">

            <Border Width="100" 
                    Height="100"
                    Background="AntiqueWhite">

                <Label Content="Test" />
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) 
        {
            PopupWindow.IsOpen = true;

            var point = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
            PopupWindow.HorizontalOffset = point.X;
            PopupWindow.VerticalOffset = point.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**`Edit: An easier solution`**

You can just set `Placement="Mouse"` for *`Popup`* instead receive coordinates of the mouse:

**`XAML`**

```
<Grid>
    <Popup Name="PopupWindow"
           Placement="Mouse"
           IsOpen="False"
           StaysOpen="False">

        <Border Width="100" 
                Height="100"
                Background="AntiqueWhite">

            <Label Content="Test" />
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            PopupWindow.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```