# WPF visibility change of window by mouse pointer change

Tags: wpf

I am develovp my application in WPF, it is screen recording app. So when the user click on record menu, a window will open and recording the screen. I want to change the recording screen based on mouse pointer change. When the user start the record the window will close, and if the user move the pointer into a particular point in the window, need to show the record window options.

[image]

Comment: Does it have anything to do with `WinForms`?

Comment: tried - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742549/open-a-small-floating-window-at-cursor-position

Answer (score 0):

You could position a transparent control in the area where you want the mouse pointer to be in when the record options need to show.

Then use a data trigger to alter the visibility of the record options.

See below for an example which demonstrates this.  Note that there is a 2-row grid into which the hover area and the recording area would be placed, but you can adapt this.

```
<Grid Name="GridMouseHover" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" />

<Grid Background="Red" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=GridMouseHover}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=GridMouseHover}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```